# Google Migration Marketplace app to OAuth 2.0

Tags: google-chrome, oauth, google-oauth

I need the application created in previous version of `Google Apps Marketplace` migrate from `OAuth 1.0 to OAuth 2.0`.

I have created a new application in Chrome Web Store as it is described in [Google Apps Marketplace: using the UpgradeableApp API](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v1migratev2). However, I do not see the field Chrome Webstore Item Id in the Marketplace interface. I guess it is because the old application was not published - there was not need for that, since it is a test app.

I need to test the migration on the test app before I could move to production. Are there any options to do that?

Is there possible to change the Chrome Webstore Item Id after I have provided it? I mean is it possible to migrate an old application to different new ones?